# Scope with order in Rails 3.2.11 on has_one association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my Rails 3.2.11 app I have a scope that I'm trying to order by based on an associated attribute. In my case I have a User model and a Profile model. The User has_one Profile, and my scope is on an attribute on the profiles table. Here's the scope:

**In `User.rb`:**

```
def self.with_default_show
  joins(:profile).where("profiles.show_all = true")
end
```

However the trouble I run into is in trying to declare order on that. For example, running:

```
joins(:profile).where("profiles.show_all = true").order("profiles.first_name DESC")
```

Gives me an error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

I know I can do `.order("2")` but that calls the second column in my Users table, not my Profiles table. How do I properly set the order on this scope to be by profiles.first_name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working was a combination of the two answers above:

```
def self.with_default_show
  joins(:profile)
  .where(profiles: {show_all: true})
  .select('users.*, profiles.first_name')
  .order('profiles.first_name')
end
```

With the sorting working as I had hoped.

Answer (score 2):

The ORDER BY clause can only be applied after the DISTINCT has been applied.

Also you must explicitly select for the clause you are ordering by.

```
User.select('profiles.*, profiles.first_name')
       .joins(:profile)
       .where("profiles.show_all = true")
       .order("profiles.first_name DESC")
```

As shown above, in order for your query to return the Profile attributes, you must explicitly select them also.

Comment: Thanks. If I change my scope to that I get a "syntax error at or near "DESC". `SELECT DISTINCT profiles.*, profiles.first_name DESC FROM`.

Comment: removed `desc` from select as it will come in `order by` ..See my updated post above.